# SQL Server Sch-S locks on unrelated tables

Tags: sql-server, locking, blocking

I am a bit confused. I myself am MCSE and thought I would understand most parts of the SQL Server.

Now I have a stored procedure here, doing inserts and updates on two tables dbo.tabA and dbo.tabB. Let's call this SPID 1.

On a complete different table sales.invoices I am recreating a clustered index on a partition scheme. Let's call this SPID 2.

To my surprise SPID 1 is blocked by SPID 2.

Looking into sys.dm_tran_locks, it tells me that SPID 1 is waiting for a Sch-S lock on sales.invoices (OBJECT LOCK) but  sales.invoices is neither mentioned directly in the SPID 2 query nor is it part of any view or function.

Why is SPID 1 trying to achieve a lock on an object that is totally untouched by its query?

Answer (score 4):

### Potential Causes

There are two likely reasons for this

1. There's a foreign key on the table
2. There's a trigger on the table

There are less likely reasons, too

1. Computed column based on a scalar function
2. Indexed view maintenance

There's also the possibility that the blocking is due to metadata changing, where modifications to system views can block each other.

### Figuring It Out

You can use [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/).

If you run it like so: `sp_WhoIsActive @get_locks = 1;`, it should help you get to the root of your blocking issue.